# gerador de código de produto

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Olá, estou fazendo um site para fazer controle de estoque, ao cadastrar um item preciso gerar um código único para cada um e queria fazer isso automaticamente! Como posso fazer? Podem me ajudar e explicar pfv?

Comment: apresente a parte do codigo correspondente ao que si refere para que possam  analisar e ter uma ideia do que se trara.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

PHP

```
function generateRandomCode($length) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $code = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomIndex = rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1);
        $code .= $characters[$randomIndex];
    }

    return $code;
}

// Exemplo de uso:
$randomCode = generateRandomCode(8);
echo $randomCode;
```

JS

```
function generateRandomCode(length) {
    var characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var code = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
        code += characters.charAt(randomIndex);
    }

    return code;
}

// Exemplo de uso:
var randomCode = generateRandomCode(8);
console.log(randomCode);
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Exemplo em: https://imasters.com.br/back-end/gerando-uuids-em-php-com-ramsey-uuid